# Rebuilding custom index not working at all

Tags: indexing, lucene

I took backup of running site and setup in my development environment, when I rebuild custom indexes on staging (CM) under data/indexs folder I can see all files are updated but on production (CD) index files are not updated i can see it by their date and time modified and also by seeing only two initial files in the index folder.

As there is no any kind of change in config files index should be build what should i consider to check? I did not see any warning etc in log file.

I republished all items, and tried different strategies but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you have separate CD and CA Servers you would use the OnPublishEndAsync strategy, this is defined like so:

```
<onPublishEndAsync type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.
           OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">web</param>
          <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
</onPublishEndAsync>
```

This monitors the OnPublishEnd event and uses the EventQueue object to publish remotely to update the indexes on the CD Servers.

Therefore you need to ensure you have the EnableEventQueues setting is set to true on the CA server with a patch file like so:

```
<setting name="EnableEventQueues">
        <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

There is more info on this here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

and here:

http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/07/sitecore-event-queue-scalability-king.html

Comment: I checked with my configuration as advised above, but they are correct

Comment: Ok. do you see anything in your event queue tables in the database when you publish an item?

Comment: I believe you are taking me to right direction, i can see all items i want to index in event queue table, what should i  check further

Comment: Further more, to ensure i deleted items from table, and noticed that they are created when i publish items, but when i build index they are not created, even though items created in table when i publish but still not indexing

Comment: I'm still stuck with issue, is there any body else to help, thanks.

Comment: Is your strategy for sitecore_web_index onPublishEndAsync?